# Checking if a point is on a line segment, works except in some cases (rounding error?)

Tags: c#, math, precision

For the issue below, is it a matter of I'm so close to zero but comparing zero with a tolerance won't work? The more precise the numbers, the more my check for an arc's point on a line fails and the less precise the more it works. The CAD drawing does have an arc that has a point on a line segment and that is where I get my input co-ordinates from for this test.

```
class Line
{
   public Point Point1 {get;set;}
   public Point Point2 {get;set;}
   public Line(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
   {
      Point1 = new Point(x1,y1); Point2 = new Point(x2,y2);
   }
}

class Point
{ 
   public double X {get;set;}
   public double Y {get;set;}
   public Point (double x, double y)
   {
       X = x; Y = y;
  }
}

//4 decimal place numbers, works
Point arcEnd = new Point(3.8421, 16.9538); // these numbers don't 
//3.84212141717697, 
//16.9538136440052
Point arcStart = new Point(4.0921, 17.2038);

//test an arc point on/off the line
Line line = new Line(3.9336, 16.9538, 3.7171, 16.9538); 
//these numbers don't 3.93362776812308, 16.9538136440053, 
//3.71712141717697, 16.9538136440054

bool on_line = Sign(line.Point1, line.Point2, arcEnd) //true

//more precise numbers, from CAD / dxf drawing for line and arc, arc end 
//point touches somewhere on the line (included in comments above, fail)
//so on_line = true for the above inputs and the Sign function gives zero, 
//but when using the commented precise numbers sign gives back 1 and the 
//value computed in sign is 3.0639866299190109E-14.




public static bool Sign(Point Point1, Point Point2, Point point)
{
    double value = (Point2.X - Point1.X) * (p.Y - Point1.Y) - (Point2.Y - Point1.Y) * (p.X - Point1.X);

    return Equals(Math.Sign(value), 0);
}

public static bool Equals(double d1, double d2, double tolerance=0.000001)
{
    double a = Math.Abs(d1 - d2);
    double b = Math.Abs(d1 * tolerance);

    if (a <= b)
    {
       return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Reviewed formulas and stack overflow, the algorithm works a majority of the time but found cases it fails and I traced it to the included example and identified my check is giving back Sign = 1 not Sign = 0 for the above inputs and more precision.

Comment: Disregarding the fact this has errors in it (which you should have fixed) and your wording is ambiguous. are you saying if i input the other values scattered around in comments, that it should equal false or true? As both tests equal true for me

Comment: Can you perhaps, fix your errors, and make 2 simple tests to prove your point with the expected results

Comment: Your `Equals` function is a bit strange. Surely you want `if (a <= tolerance)`?

Comment: @John: it may or may not be the best way for them to write the method, but it seems clear that it is what they _want_. That is, the method scales `d1` by the `tolerance` value, and uses that as the threshold for equality. Personally, I think that's wrong, because how far apart two numbers need to be for them to not be equal any more shouldn't have anything to do with the _magnitude_ of those numbers -- after all, doing it this way would mean that nothing could be equal to `0`, while very large numbers can be far apart and still equal.

Comment: As @TheGeneral suggests, your question is in great need of improvement. Please fix it so it includes a good [mcve], with a detailed explanation of what that code does, what you expected/wanted it to do instead, and what _specifically_ you need help with. What have you done to try to figure it out, and where are you stuck? (The code above is clearly just bogus, because you can't return a `bool` in a method declared as returning `int`)

Comment: Sorry about that, changed int to bool (error when copying over the console application test).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made two mistakes. First, you used Sign function in "Return Equals(Math.Sign(value), 0);", which will give you the value of 1 for any positive number and value of -1 for any negative number. This will destroy your attempt to use tolerance. Second, you tried to compare the difference with a ratio of the first number "b = Math.Abs(d1 * tolerance)", which will always return False. I recommend you compare it with tolerance itself, like this.

```
public static bool Sign(Point Point1, Point Point2, Point point)
{
    double value = (Point2.X - Point1.X) * (point.Y - Point1.Y) - (Point2.Y - Point1.Y) * (point.X - Point1.X);
    return Equals(value, 0);
}

public static bool Equals(double d1, double d2, double tolerance = 0.000001)
{
    double a = Math.Abs(d1 - d2);
    if (a <= tolerance)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, The goal was to use one calculation that identified if it fell on a line or could be considered "inside / to the left" or "outside / to the right" and begin working towards a way to identify points could be contained inside some other complex shape.  Struggling with basic examples I am hoping to slowly build up the solution working with CAD drawings.

Comment: Then you should make these two tasks separately. First check if it is on the line using `return Equals(value, 0)` and if it is not on the line you can use `Math.Sign(value)` to determine its position secondly.